$f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ is biholomorphic

Let $\mathbb{H}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \Im (z) >0\}$
\begin{align*}
f: \ &\mathbb{H} \to D(0,1)\\
&z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i} 
\end{align*}
Show that $f$ is bi-holomorphic ($f$ is a bijection with $f,f^{-1}$ holomorphic).

Firstly, to see that f is well-defined, we must show that $\frac{z-i}{z+i} \in D(0,1); \forall z \in \mathbb{H}$:
\begin{align*}
|z-i|^2&=(z-i)\overline{(z-i)}\\[8pt]
&=(z-i)(\overline{z}+i)\\[8pt]
&=z\overline{z}+iz-i\overline{z}+1\\[8pt]
&=z\overline{z}+2i^2\Big(\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}\Big)+1 \\[8pt]
&=z\overline{z}-2\Im (z)+1\\[8pt]
&<z\overline{z}+2\Im (z)+1 \quad (\Im (z)>0) \\[8pt]
&=(z+i)(\overline{z}-i)=|z+i|^2
\end{align*}
So, $|\frac{z-i}{z+i}|^2<1 \rightarrow |\frac{z-i}{z+i}|<1$
To show that $f$ is bijective, I compute explicitly its inverse and arrived at:
$$f^{-1}(z)=-i\big(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\big)$$
And as $f;f^{-1}$ are the product of two holomorphic functions, we can conclude that they are holomorphic as they are the composition of holomorphic functions in their domains.
Is the justification correct? Should the point justifying that $f;f^{-1}$ are holomorphic be more detailed? Any other suggestions?

Everything seems OK, except that in the next-to-last paragraph you start with the product of two holomorphic functions and end up with the composition of holomorphic functions. How did you get from product to composition?

I was considering the function that it's the pointwise product of two complex functions and I could regard the product of two holomorphic functions as a composition of functions; is this acceptable?
